# what is good teshuva book

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, yom-kippur, repentance-teshuvah, elul

Elul and Yom Kippur are flying by fast. I am looking for something uplifting.

Books on teshuva are usually quite depressing; too much talk about gehinom.
Not that it's not good, just that it doesn't work so well for me.

Comment: "too much talk about gehinom"? What books have you been reading??

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45252/170

Answer (score 4):

[Gates of Repentance](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/38229) (Sha'arei Teshuvah) by Rabbeinu Yonah of Gerona.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Igeres Hatshuva by Rabbi Shnuer Zalman of Liadi. An excellent translation and commentary is [available online](http://beta.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7877/jewish/Igeret-HaTeshuva.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Reb Meir Stern teaches Rambam Hilchos Teshuva like I have written [elsewhere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47498/5323). I would recommend you listen to a shiur on the Rambam from YUTorah etc.

Comment: "elsewhere" == http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47498/5323 ?

Comment: I was just taking a guess at what you meant by "*like I have written elsewhere*" ....if I'm right I'd advise [edit]ing that in....doesn't hurt to cross-reference information.

Answer (score 1):

- [Orhhot Tzadiqim](http://hebrewbooks.org/38360) (a.k.a. *Sefer HaMiddot*) by *Unknown*
- [Mesillat Yesharim](http://hebrewbooks.org/52042) ("Path of the Just") by HaRav Moshe Hayim from Luzzato

Generally, I find books of *mussar* (i.e. character development) to assist in teshuvah.

Answer (score 0):

One Elul I gained a lot from [Waking Up Just in Time](https://books.google.com/books/about/Waking_Up_Just_in_Time.html?id=HIAXfbZwxwAC) by Rabbi Dr. Abraham J. Twerski.
Another year I read [Elul](http://www.rabbidovidgoldwasser.com/books.html#elul) by Rabbi Dovid Goldwasser

Both not hard core but inspirational