# Looking for a list of Sefarim on Teshuva

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, repentance-teshuvah

As Elul approaches, I am curious about a list of Seforim that are focused on Teshuva. The starting point, of course, is Shaarei Teshuva by Rabbeinu Yonah. The seforim could be all Hebrew, all English, and could date back all the way from Chazal until today. Thank you!

Note: if someone wants to make a community wiki that works, as I believe many will truly benefit from a list of Seforim on this topic.

Comment: related: [what is good teshuva book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19046/11501)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, and with a specific focus on the High Holiday period, you have

- the [translation](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422618172.html) of Shaarei Teshuva
- R Heshy Kleinman's [The Power of Teshuvah](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422611098.html) (he is the author of the Praying with fire series)
- R Immanuel Bernstein's [Teshuvah, A Guide for the Mind and Heart During Elul, Rosh Hashanah & Yom Kippur](https://mosaicapress.com/product/teshuvah/)
- R Reuven Leuchter's [Teshuvah, Restoring Life](https://www.feldheim.com/teshuvah-restoring-life)
- Erica Brown's [Return: Daily Inspiration for the Days of Awe](https://korenpub.com/collections/dr-erica-brown/products/returnhardcover)

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is the Hebrew  Wikipedia page on Teshuva.  At the bottom of that page it has a list of seforim and sources on the topic.

[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/תשובה_(יהדות)](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94_(%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA))

The top few mentioned there (aside from Rabbeinu Yona) among many more are the following:

- משנה תורה לרמב"ם הלכות תשובה
- המהר"ל מפראג, ספר נתיב התשובה
- רבי שניאור
  זלמן מליאדי (אדמו"ר הזקן), איגרת התשובה - החלק השלישי בספר התניא.
- ראי"ה קוק, אורות התשובה

Comment: Could you mention some, in case the link is broken?

Comment: Here are the top few mentioned there.  I doubt the wikipedia link will be broken anytime soon.
That page has received consistent edits since 2004.
משנה תורה לרמב"ם הלכות תשובה
המהר"ל מפראג, ספר נתיב התשובה
רבי שניאור זלמן מליאדי (אדמו"ר הזקן), איגרת התשובה - החלק השלישי בספר התניא.
ראי"ה קוק, אורות התשובה

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another one is the [חבור התשובה](https://hebrewbooks.org/41637) by the Meiri. In addition, many seforim that deal with Elul and Rosh Hashanah/ Yom Kippur deal with Teshuva. And you can check a seforim store for English works, such as [this one.](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422611159.html)

Comment: But personally I highly recommend Shaarei Teshuva.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [On Repentance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592644783)/על התשובה by Rav J.B. Soloveitchik